# How to implement a Jtable in Intellij using UI Designer

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

So, I am using Intellij IDEA 2017 Community. I am working with java Swing components. I have been trying to get a simple JTable to show up on my GUI, but have had no success. The program starts fine, there are no errors, but the table does not get created correctly. I see tons of questions about JTable, and I have tried all of their solutions without success.

A lot of the solutions state to create a new object for the JScrollPane and JTable, but Intellij states "Assignment to UI-bound field will overwrite field generated by UI Designer. I even ignored this and tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623957/how-to-display-a-jtable-in-a-jpanel-with-java) without success.

I created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/397c48c3f2f06aff022578f73e1cbe26) of my code which has not worked. I followed [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for creating Jtables. I am just not sure what I am doing wrong.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119778/working-with-jtable-in-intellij-idea), suggestions 3 solutions. The only one I haven't tried is the custom Create solution. That will be my next attempt, but I would really like to get the table.setModel solution to work. I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688183/how-to-initiate-a-jtable-in-a-swing-gui), and also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943190/intellij-jtable-in-jscrollpane?rq=1) which have not helped me solve this problem. Any help will be great!

For reference:
Image of my GUI
[image]

Preview of my GUI

[image]

Comment: `Any help will be great!` - don't use the designer. You are spending time learning a tool and the code will not be maintainable if you move to another IDE. So learn how to create your own GUI forms manually and just use the IDE as a tool to compile and debug etc. So first learn to create a simple frame with just a JTable added to a JScrollPane and the scrollpane added to the frame. If you then  need help you can post a proper [mcve] in the forum (not on github) because the entire code will only be about 15 lines.

Comment: Your gist will fail with a `NullPointerException` because `taskManager` isn't initialised - Frankly, I've never understood IntelliJ's form editor, so I've never bothered with it

Comment: Okay, I will work on just creating my own GUI forms manually, but will leave this question up to see if there is an answer. Also, taskManager is initialized by the GUI designer I think. If I try to initialize it, I get the warning mentioned above. It works without initializing the objects except for the frame.